# phpmyadmin is truncating the last field when importing from a CVS file

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a column of datatype `VARCHAR(250)`.

However, when I import from a CSV file, text to be stored in this column is being cut short. For example:

> E:\English\2011 and 2012 updates\100 Hits - DMG100072 - Movies Karaoke\DMG100072-1

is being truncated to

> E:\English\2011 and 2012 updates\100 Hits - DMG100.

In other words, all of the fields are cut to 50 characters. What could be the cause of this issue and what are possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY instead of ENCLOSED BY 
 Check this link for more information : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html